# Is distribution of raring packages officially ended?

Tags: 13.04, repository

I don't see raring on http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/. Is it a temporary thing or people are expected to move to next versions of Ubuntu ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Raring went End of Life some time ago.  [All releases of Ubuntu](http://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) have specific End of Life dates.  The wiki contains a page of all Releases, both current releases and releases that have gone End of Life, where they are no longer supported, and no longer should be used.  **It is infinitely important that you use a version of Ubuntu that is still supported so that you do not put yourself and your data at risk.**

The "repositories" for older releases of Ubuntu are under [this location](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/) but never receive updates or security fixes.  **Continuing to use an older release that has gone End of Life puts you and your data at risk.**